# Javascript Files linked to HTML are no longer founded without Live Server extension, WHY?

Tags: javascript, html, localhost, src, file-not-found

I am using a `visual studio code` program, and I have an extension that allows Live Local Host so I can change code and see the change on `HTML` without refreshing it every time I make a change and save it. It was fine when I start it with that. but I notice when I open up the HTML itself, it causes an error of not be able to find files that are linked to HTML such as multiple `javascript` files and `jquery` library and stuff.

```
Index.html:14 GET file:///C:/Game%20Projects/The%20Grand%20Hunt%20CYOA/Events/Introduction.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Index.html:16 GET file:///C:/Game%20Projects/The%20Grand%20Hunt%20CYOA/Characters/Character%20Customization.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Index.html:18 GET file:///C:/Game%20Projects/The%20Grand%20Hunt%20CYOA/Functions&Variables/Clean.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Index.html:20 GET file:///C:/Game%20Projects/The%20Grand%20Hunt%20CYOA/Events/Main%20Menu.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Index.html:22 GET file:///C:/Game%20Projects/The%20Grand%20Hunt%20CYOA/Default/Systems.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Index.html:24 GET file:///C:/Game%20Projects/The%20Grand%20Hunt%20CYOA/Events/Equipment.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Index.html:26 GET file:///C:/Game%20Projects/The%20Grand%20Hunt%20CYOA/Characters/Inventory.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Index.html:28 GET file:///C:/Game%20Projects/The%20Grand%20Hunt%20CYOA/Events/Store.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

And here the HTML that I use to link those. Am I doing linking wrong that is somehow fine with `localhost` live extension? This is extension name, "Live Server".

```
<head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=NO, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Arts/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></script>

    <script src="/jQuery.js" type="text/jQuery"></script>

    <script src="/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Events/Introduction.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Characters/Character Customization.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Functions&Variables/Clean.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Events/Main Menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Default/Systems.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Events/Equipment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Characters/Inventory.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Game Projects/The Grand Hunt CYOA/Events/Store.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>The Grand Hunt CYOA, creator: /u/Feather_Snake</title>

  </head>
```

Comment: could you share the folder structure ?

Answer (score 0):

i couldnt find the answer to the others but the css should be

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="the url that the style is on">
```